# How did the map2_dbl know what its arguments were in this instance?

Tags: r, purrr

I am reading [Wickham's book](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/model-basics.html) and I came across this block of code:

```
models <- models %>% 
mutate(dist = purrr::map2_dbl(a1, a2, sim1_dist))

models

> # A tibble: 250 × 3
>       a1      a2  dist
>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 -15.15  0.0889  30.8
> 2  30.06 -0.8274  13.2
> 3  16.05  2.2695  13.2
> 4 -10.57  1.3769  18.7
> 5 -19.56 -1.0359  41.8#> 6   7.98  4.5948  19.3
>  ... with 244 more rows
```

I would've thought this code should produce an error; the tibble "models" is an argument of the mutate function; I am very surprised that the function map2_dbl knew to go back there to find a1, a2.

I would have expected it was neccesary to do something like this:

```
mutate(dist = purrr::map2_dbl(models$a1, models$a2, sim1_dist))
```

My question is: is this a normal behavior for functions in R, or is there something special about the map2_dbl or mutate functions? Are there any other functions which exhibit this behavior?

Comment: the [`%>%` operator](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) passes the left-hand side object into the right-hand side. So the function following the `%>%` is aware of the object already

Comment: @SymbolixAU I agree that the mutate function should be aware of "models", but I am surprised that the argument of the mutant function, map2_dbl is aware of it also.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I guess using the %>% operator is in some sense stronger than just doing     mutate(models, dist = purrr::map2_dbl(a1, a2, sim1_dist))? I tried this and it did not work.

Comment: If you look [in the source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/blob/master/R/pipe.R) it might give you an idea about how it keeps track of environments and function arguments.

Comment: You don't need to refer to `a1` and `a2` as `models$a1` and `models$a2` because the pipe `%>%` after `models` makes it possible to refer to columns of a data frame without explicitly mentioning data frame name. `a1` and `a2` are now also vectors which can be fed directly into `map2_dbl`

Comment: `mutate( models, dist = purrr::map2_dbl(a1, a2, sim1_dist) )` should work. What error is it giving you?

Comment: @ArtemSokolov Sorry my mistake; in my own code I have the columns named as a_1 and a_2 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a property of [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), which `mutate` and other verbs in the `dplyr` package use extensively. This is not specific to `dplyr` or other packages, however. Consider `subset` from the base R:

```
## Create a simple data frame
X <- data.frame( a = 1:5, b = 11:15 )

## Notice that I can refer to the columns a and b without doing X$a and X$b
subset( X, a > 1 & b < 15 )
#   a  b
# 2 2 12
# 3 3 13
# 4 4 14
```

As others have pointed out, the `%>%` pipe operator simply takes its left-hand argument and passes it to its right-hand argument, making the following equivalent to the above:

```
X %>% subset( a > 1 & b < 15 )
```